# Widget not going to bottom of screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I'm trying to get the REGISTER button to align on the bottom center of the screen. I'm relatively new to Flutter and am wondering if there is a way to do this easily, or do I need to rewrite a lot of code? Here's what I have so far. As you can see, I put it in an Align(), but it only goes to the bottom center of the filled area. I think what I have to do is make the outside Container() the height of the entire screen, but I also don't know how to do this. If you have a way to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginSignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginSignupScreenState createState() => _LoginSignupScreenState();
}

class _LoginSignupScreenState extends State<LoginSignupScreen> {
  // TRUE: register page, FALSE: login page
  bool _register = true;

  void _changeScreen() {
    setState(() {
      // sets it to the opposite of the current screen
      _register = !_register;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
//      height:,
      child: Column(
//      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ButtonBar(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: _changeScreen,
                      child: Text('REGISTER'),
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: _changeScreen,
                      child: Text('LOGIN'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'E-MAIL'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'USERNAME'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'PASSWORD'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () => {},
              child: Text(_register ? 'REGISTER' : 'LOGIN'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You will solve using [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.

```
        Expanded(
          child: Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () => {},
              child: Text(_register ? 'REGISTER' : 'LOGIN'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 46):

There is an easier way:

```
return Scaffold(     
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Text('bottom screen widget'),
    elevation: 0,
  ),
  body: Text('body')
  );
```

Comment: Just to add to this - depending on your target device you may want to wrap your bottomNavigationBar widget in a SafeArea otherwise it may be partially covered by the home bar (iPhone)

Answer (score 17):

There is another way to solve this:

```
children : [
           ///1
           Button(),

           Expanded(child:Container()),

           ///2
           Button(),
           ]
```

Logic: by expanded container will absorb the middle space in between the two buttons by which the second button will placed at bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the `Container` height to cover the entire screen as you mentioned and then just wrap your `Align` widget inside an `Expanded` widget, which will fill the available space.

Try this code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ButtonBar(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: _changeScreen,
                      child: Text('REGISTER'),
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: _changeScreen,
                      child: Text('LOGIN'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'E-MAIL'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'USERNAME'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'PASSWORD'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                child: Text(_register ? 'REGISTER' : 'LOGIN'),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap all widgets with `Expanded` Widget excluding the last one, `Expanded` widget basically takes max available space. Look at the below example you will get to know

**Code:**

```
Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          /// Below container will go to bottom
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){},
            child: Text('Click'),

          )
        ],
      ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try This :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginSignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginSignupScreenState createState() => _LoginSignupScreenState();
}

class _LoginSignupScreenState extends State<LoginSignupScreen> {
  // TRUE: register page, FALSE: login page
  bool _register = true;

  void _changeScreen() {
    setState(() {
      // sets it to the opposite of the current screen
      _register = !_register;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
//      height:,
        child: Column(
//      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: _changeScreen,
                        child: Text('REGISTER'),
                      ),
                      MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: _changeScreen,
                        child: Text('LOGIN'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'E-MAIL'),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'USERNAME'),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'PASSWORD'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Text(_register ? 'REGISTER' : 'LOGIN'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with bottomNavigationBar

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: YourButtonWidget(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Spacer()` widget before Register Button

```
class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<TestApp> {
  bool _register = true;

  void _changeScreen() {
    setState(() {
      // sets it to the opposite of the current screen
      _register = !_register;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hospital Management"),
      ),
      body: Container(
//      height:,
      child: Column(
//      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ButtonBar(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: _changeScreen,
                      child: Text('REGISTER'),
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: _changeScreen,
                      child: Text('LOGIN'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'E-MAIL'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'USERNAME'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'PASSWORD'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () => {},
              child: Text(_register ? 'REGISTER' : 'LOGIN'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SingleChildScrollView` with `SixedBox` height to screen size. Here in the below code, Text will appear in top and content that need to display at bottom is separated by `Spacer()` and finally button is placed

```
  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 21,),
           child: SizedBox(
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
           child: Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           children: [
            Text( "Address",
            style: TextStyle( color: YourColor,
           fontSize: YourSize,
           fontWeight: YourFontWeight
            ),
            ),
            spacer(), //after spacer contentwill diplay at the bottom ofscreen
            /// Below button will go to bottom
             ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){},
              child: Text('Click'),
            ),   
     ]  
   ))   
 );  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I needed to do this in my Drawer, and I managed to do it by adding Center and then Align widget by setting the `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter`. The code looks like this:

```
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Center(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Logout', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOutUser();
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```